# Can we update two tables in 1 query postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am using postgres as my database and have 2 tables

```
accounts
id | name | status


accountOwner
account_id | user_id
```

I have user_id(accountOwner table) and status(accounts table) to be updated based on accountid I have. Is it possible to update both the tables in 1 query? I tried the following

```
UPDATE accounts,accountOwner SET accounts.status='active', accountOwner.user_id=3 WHERE  accounts.id=accountOwner.account_id AND accountOwner.account_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you **cannot** update two tables at once. [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-update.html) says:

> UPDATE -- update rows of **a table**

However, you can use a **FROM** clause, for example:

```
UPDATE accounts SET status = 'active'
  FROM accountOwners
  WHERE accounts.id = accountOwners.account_id
  AND accountOwners.account_id = 1;
```

Comment: Your solution is the right one, but one `UPDATE` statement *can* update two tables: `WITH sub AS (UPDATE table1 ... RETURNING ...) UPDATE table2 ...`.